# Can you open a web browser restricted to localhost access only?

Tags: browser

I want to open a web browser (firefox / chromium) to access a web app running on localhost. I need all other network access disabled. For example, if I run wireshark, I should see no external requests to public search engines, dns resolvers, or telemetry endpoints from the web browser. Is this possible using tools within the browser or flags on the command line?

Comment: Can you set the browser to use a proxy running on localhost which restricts this for you? Although note that Chromium does not honor proxy settings for all of its behavior.

Comment: Yes, this may be an option. I'm hoping for something I can use natively within the browser and it's important the browser can only communicate with localhost. So no telemetry either.

Comment: @mageeeeep Why not just disconnect from your network? If you need your browser to access nothing but localhost, then the quickest and dumbest way to get that is to make it unaware there's an Internet. Is your desired usage perhaps more complex?

Comment: @mageeeeep Do you need to prevent the browser from communicating outside localhost even with malicious actors running code on the browser? As in, would the browser bypassing localhost be strictly a _security issue_?

Comment: I would like the option to access the LAN while using the restricted browser. The browser should just be a simple UI. It's not actually to sandbox a malicious website, I just want to access a local web app without the browser communicating to the public internet. I would like the browser to run silently if that makes sense.

Comment: What's the purpose? Is this for testing? In other words, do you need to be able to use your GUI to open up a browser and go to localhost:$PORT? Or do you want to use a headless browser for this?

Comment: I'm trying to access an app like vscode server running as a docker container. The idea being to customize these ide environments as containers and run them in a pentest environment as a forced "offline mode". I want to use the container locally and there should never be any connection to the public net or LAN. I can sandbox the app itself in a container but you need a user interface to access the app like a web browser.

Comment: Sounds like you need a quarantined virtual machine to act as a sandbox. Does that address your usage?

Comment: Yes, that would work. I am hoping for something a little more ergonomic.

Comment: You could use a [pac file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config) to allow DIRECT access to localhost and PROXY everything else to some non-existing IP:port. Such pac file can be given for example as `--proxy-pac-url` in chrome.

Comment: This is rather a question on software settings, if you don't have security concern you want to address, than this should be on Superuser substack

Comment: If you're on Linux using namespaces could be the answer - check out [Firejail](https://firejail.wordpress.com/documentation-2/firefox-guide/) for example.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest option might be to create a copy of the browser executable (a symlink or hardlink would be more convenient but might not work if you're on Windows) and set a firewall rule for the executable's new name that prevents outbound requests to non-loopback addresses. The reason using a link might not work is that the Windows kernel considers a process image to be based on the canonical name of the file, and will resolve links to find this. If that image name is what the firewall rule filter uses... well, hard links might work (or might not, depending on how Windows handles such cases) but symlinks wouldn't (or rather, you'd have to create one for the entire browser, not just for its alternate name). I don't think Linux is as adamant about finding the canonical image name but I've never tried to build such a rule either.

A better option might be to install another browser that you use exclusively for this environment. There are no lack of browsers out there, most based on Chromium but a few on Firefox. There's even IE, if you don't need support for the latest web standards and are on Windows; you probably aren't using it for anything else. An advantage of using a whole different browser (aside from getting around "what name are the rules applied to?") is that it can stay up to date without you needing to re-connect or re-copy the alternate name. However, the updater will of course need to run out of process to do this...

Also, note that DNS requests are not necessarily going to initiate from the browser. On OSes with a DNS resolver cache, there might be a service (daemon) that maintains it. Host-resolution APIs will usually use the cache rather than querying a DNS server directly, and the service will be the one to make DNS queries for any cache misses. You should check in Wireshark what process the requests are actually coming from.

Comment: I think NTFS supports symlinks.

Comment: @forest NTFS does, yes, as of NT 6.0 (Vista). Read the sentence starting with "The reason a link might not work", though. I have exploited this fact to get around stupid name-based filters while preserving paths (rename the actual executable, drop a link with the old name, paths to old name work but filter sees the new one) but in this case it works against us.

Answer (score 0):

I found this tool called [x11docker](https://github.com/mviereck/x11docker) which is working for me on a kali linux vmware machine.

Here is an example DockerFile which installs the firefox browser and the code-server web app. I can access code-server using firefox from within the container and there are no connections made from the main ethernet device per wireshark.

```
FROM kalilinux/kali-rolling

RUN apt-get update \
    && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y kali-desktop-xfce \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN apt-get update \
    && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y firefox-esr curl \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash kali \
    && echo 'kali:kali' | chpasswd \
    && usermod -aG sudo kali \
    && sed -i '1 i\TERM=xterm-256color' /home/kali/.bashrc \
    && echo 'Set disable_coredump false' > /etc/sudo.conf

RUN curl -fsSL https://code-server.dev/install.sh | sh
CMD code-server
USER kali
```

Here is a command to run the container using the x11docker tool (I tagged my docker image code-server):

```
x11docker --name code-server --network=none --workdir /workspace -- -v $(pwd):/workspace -- code-server
```

I was then able to exec into the container and run firefox to access the web-app running on localhost.

```
docker exec -it code-server bash
```